# python how to get data of the fancyBox?

Tags: python, fancybox, urllib

is there any way to parse fancyBox content?
there is a web page that contains a class_name with "href = #free" to the fancyBox. It includes a number of icons.
I wonder how to get the fancyBox data?

By using urlib, I can access the data of the web page as well

couldn't find any info about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using webdriver

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://...")
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath('')
content.click()
urls = re.findall('https://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', driver.page_source)
for url in urls:
   if re.match(r'https://.*(jpg|png|gif)$', url):
        f = open("C:\\..."+ url.split('icons/')[-1],'wb')
        f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
        f.close()
        print(url.split('icons/')[-1])
```